# Uninstalling Plone Theme Doesn't Remove Custom Favicon

Tags: plone, uninstallation, favicon

System Info: Mac OSX 10.7, Python 2.6.7, Plone 4.0.7

I'm creating an uninstall profile for a Plone 4 Theme, and everything has gone really smoothly except I can't get the favicon to revert back to the vanilla one. The custom icon was in my images skins directory in my skin path, both of which I've successfully removed with the uninstall profile. After refreshing any page of my site the Sunburst Theme has been applied and all is well except for the favicon. I'm doing all of my work in foreground mode so unless I'm mistaken there shouldn't be any caching causing this.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some browsers cache the favicon separately from any setting you may have for the browser cache. I wouldn't worry as long as the image you get when you call the URL (of the favicon) directly is correct.

Answer (score 4):

Favicons are often cached along with your browser History, so you might try clearing that as well as your cache.

You can also add a cache-busting query to your favicon link which should cause it to reload:

```
favicon.ico?v=123
```